# What does this curve over the C-B bond mean?

Tags: bond, structural-formula, notation

[image]

I have come across this notation in a question I am trying to answer and am unsure of what exactly it means, can anyone clarify what this represents?

Comment: That there are two such groups...

Comment: Why not mention name and author of this book?

Answer (score 1):

That ‘curve’ is a bracket, and the whole thing is a shorthand notation for ‘two of the same group’.

Thus, the molecule could be termed *bis-(3-methylbut-2-yl)borane*.

Comment: The trivial or common name is disiamylborane, with the di- confirming the above, that there are two alkyl groups attached to the BH.